# "Too many candles referenced in history" error when counting bars since highest high of last 50 bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to count number of bars since highest high of last 50 bars in pine script. But it is giving me an error:

> Study error, too many candles referenced in history

```
//@version=5
indicator("Trendline" , overlay = true)


h1=ta.highest(high, 50)
l1=ta.lowest(low, 50)
bari=ta.barssince(h1)
bari2=ta.barssince(l1)

if(barstate.islast)
highline=line.new(x1=bari, y1=high[h1], x2=bar_index, y2=high)
line.set_color(highline, color.red)
line.set_extend(highline, extend.none)
line.set_width(highline, 2)
line.delete(highline[1])``
```

Answer (score 0):

at x2, it should be the last candle (*bar_index*). so x1 must be the last candle minus 50 periods
y1 and y2, must be the value of highest high (*h1*)

Something like that:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Trendline" , overlay = true)

h1 = ta.highest(high, 50)

if(barstate.islast)
    highline=line.new(x1=bar_index - 50, y1=h1, x2=bar_index, y2=h1)
    line.set_color(highline, color.red)
    line.set_extend(highline, extend.none)
    line.set_width(highline, 2)
    line.delete(highline[1])
```